# angular unitegallery g_ugFunctions is not defined

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use angular cli 1.7.4 + angular 5.2.10 + unitegallery 1.7.28 so I use in main.ts:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import './provider-plugin';
import 'bootstrap';
import 'unitegallery/dist/js/unitegallery.js';
import 'unitegallery/dist/themes/tiles/ug-theme-tiles.js';
//
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
...
```

provider-plugin.ts (without it *unitegallery.js* reports *jQuery* is missing) is:

```
/*!
  ProvidePlugin
 */
import * as $ from 'jquery';

window['$'] = $;
window['jQuery'] = $;
window['jquery'] = $;
```

In browser I see the *vendor.bundle.js* having a proper order for *unitegallery.js* and *ug-theme-tiles.js* but when page is loading I get these errors:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: g_ugFunctions is not defined ReferenceError: g_ugFunctions is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/unitegallery/dist/themes/tiles/ug-theme-tiles.js:5:36)
    at mightThrow (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:3534:29)
    at process (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:3602:12)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:421:31)
    at Zone.runTask (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:188:47)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:496:34)
    at ZoneTask.invoke (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:485:48)
    at timer (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:2054:29) undefined
jQuery.Deferred.exceptionHook @ jquery.js:3818
process @ jquery.js:3606
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:421
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:188
ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:496
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:485
timer @ zone.js:2054
setTimeout (async)
scheduleTask @ zone.js:2075
ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:407
Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:232
Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:255
scheduleMacroTaskWithCurrentZone @ zone.js:1114
(anonymous) @ zone.js:2090
proto.(anonymous function) @ zone.js:1394
(anonymous) @ jquery.js:3640
fire @ jquery.js:3268
fireWith @ jquery.js:3398
fire @ jquery.js:3406
fire @ jquery.js:3268
fireWith @ jquery.js:3398
ready @ jquery.js:3878
completed @ jquery.js:3888
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:421
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:188
ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:496
invokeTask @ zone.js:1540
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1566

zone.js:192 Uncaught ReferenceError: g_ugFunctions is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.eval (ug-theme-tiles.js:5)
    at mightThrow (jquery.js:3534)
    at process (jquery.js:3602)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask (zone.js:496)
    at ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:485)
    at timer (zone.js:2054)
```

unitegallery.js contains the declaration:

```
var g_ugFunctions = new UGFunctions();
```

so what's the problem or how to solve this?

**EDIT**
Works fine when simply concatenating those 2 unitegallery js files:

```
// import 'unitegallery/dist/js/unitegallery.js';
// import 'unitegallery/dist/themes/tiles/ug-theme-tiles.js';
import 'unitegallery/dist/themes/tiles/unitegallery+ug-theme-tiles.js';
```

Comment: For those struggling with _unitegallery_: you'll have to also use a resolver in order for the EDIT workaround to succeed.

Comment: What resolver did you use @adrhc when I tried your solution, I get a `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve` error.

Comment: I was able to do it using gulp-concat, but for some reason many variables in the main file didn't have var in front and were causing a bunch of errors which is weird because it otherwise works.

Comment: @Mihail Minkov please check https://github.com/adrhc/albums/blob/master/src/app/app-routing.module.ts for the resolver and the component relying on it - it's a **working** single page web application using unite gallery.

Comment: Oh, I thought it was something different, I am not using angular, I am using other stuff, but anyway my problem was an inconsistency in variable definition inside the files. Still don't know why.

Comment: Oh, well, this is about unitegallery with angular so the *resolver* relates to the angular's notion of *resolver*.